# Python: Click Package - Having trouble with non ASCII chars & cmd.exe

Tags: python, encoding, click, command, line

I am writing a command line tool using the Click Python Package:
http://click.pocoo.org/5/

Which is quite usefull but I can't get one issue fixed with that, which is when I enter non ASCII chars as parameter for my Command Line Tool, it will always give me that encoding error:[image]

And yeah I know about encode() and decode() in python, but as you can see in my code I am not touching this string anywhere.

Is it the fault of my console? Am I missing any settings here? I am using Windows 7 cmd.exe and know that Windows likes his own encoding for filenames etc. Do I have to use another console? Tried python one with same result.

The click Documentation states all strings are treated as Unicode...

I would appreciate your help really much.
Installing click is as easy as *pip install click*

Kind regards,

Marcurion

My Code:

```
import click
from click_shell import shell
import os



@shell(prompt='Tool > ', intro='some test...', hist_file=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
def stRec():
    pass



@stRec.command()
@click.argument('name', required=True, type=click.STRING)
def set(name):
    print "nothing"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    stRec()
```

Comment: Can you add  ```-*- coding: utf-8 -*-``` in top of your file. this may be work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately no, error still persists

Answer (score 0):

I found it out, had to add this on top of the other import statements (all lines are important):

```
#!/usr/bin/python -S

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1252")
import site
```

cp1252 is the encoding reported to me by

```
import locale
print locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

However the encoding of my "name" parameter was not cp1252 when I got it, had to find out with chardet lib (*pip install chardet*)that it was actually ISO-8859-9. So since I wanted to create a folder with this argument I encoded it back to cp1252:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -S

import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("cp1252")
import site

import click
from click_shell import shell
import os

import locale
import chardet

@shell(prompt='Tool > ', intro='some test...', hist_file=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
def stRec():
    pass



@stRec.command()
@click.argument('name', required=True, type=click.STRING)
def set(name):
    # Create folder in the folder running this script
    folderPath = os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0], name)
    folderPath = folderPath.decode(str(chardet.detect(bytes(folderPath))['encoding'])).encode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
    if not os.path.exists(folderPath):
        os.makedirs(folderPath)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    stRec()
```